# How to read .xlsm files in a folder, a folder that is present in different folders using R

Tags: r

I have directory with a list of folders which contains a folder named "ABC" . This "ABC" has '.xlsm' files. I want to use a R code to read '.xlsm' files in the folder "ABC", which under different folders in a directory.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the paths to each file, then simply use `read_excel` from the `readxl` package:

```
library(readxl)
mydata <- read_excel("ABC/myfile.xlsm")
```

If you first need to get the paths to each file, you can use a system command (I'm on Ubuntu 18.04) to find all of the paths and store them in a vector.  You can then import them one at a time:

```
myshellcommand <- "find /path/to/top/directory -path '*/ABC/*' -type d"
mypaths <- system(command = myshellcommand, intern = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your directory requirements, one method for finding all of the files can be a double `list.files`:

```
ld <- list.files(pattern="^ABC$", include.dirs=TRUE, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
lf <- list.files(ld, pattern="\\.xlsm$", ignore.case=TRUE, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
```

To read them all into a list (good ref for dealing with a list-of-frames: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272):

```
lstdf <- sapply(lf, read_excel, simplify=FALSE)
```

This defaults to opening the first sheet in each workbook. Other options in `readxl::read_excel` that might be useful: `sheet=`, `range=`, `skip=`, `n_max=`.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of `*.xlsm` files in your working directory you can do the following:

```
list.files(
    path = getwd(),
    pattern = glob2rx(pattern = "*.xlsm"),
    full.names = TRUE,
    recursive = TRUE
) -> files_to_read

lst_dta <- lapply(
    X = files_to_read,
    FUN = function(x) {
        cat("Reading:", x, fill = TRUE)
        openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = x)
    }
)
```

## Results

Given two files, each with two columns `A`, `B` and `C`, `D` the generated list corresponds to:

```
>> lst_dta
[[1]]
  C D
1 3 4

[[2]]
  A B
1 1 2
```

## Notes

- This will read all `.xlsm` files found in the directory tree starting from `getwd()`.
- [`openxlsx`](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx) is efficient due to the use of Rcpp. If you are going to be handling a substantial amount of MS Excel files this package is worth exploring, IMHO.

---

## Edit

As pointed out by [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) in comments, you may want to read `*.xlsm` files that reside *only* within `ABC` folder ignoring `*.xlsm` files outside the `ABC` folder. You could filter your files vector in the following manner:

```
grep(pattern = "ABC", x = files_to_read, value = TRUE)
```

Unlikely, if you have `*.xlsm` files that have `ABC` string in names and are saved outside `ABC` folder you may get extra matches.

Comment: Given the premise that only the XLSM files within "ABC" directories are of interest, this may identify extra files if other non-ABC-based files exist.